# What is a noun for "nice revenge"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I get revenge on someone, it means payback, but with negative connotations.

Now let's say someone does a good deed for me, and I repay their kindness in some way. Is there a noun along the lines of, "I have got revenge on them, but good for good"?

Comment: Your very definition of revenge itself is flawed.You reciprocate acts of kindness, not avenge them.

Comment: Should I update the Q?

Comment: Reciprocity is a useful form of the word.

Comment: Reciprocate. is the verb.

Comment: In India, I have heard people use a similar term 'sweet revenge'. E.g., You proposed a girl, but she didn't accept it.  Later, you happen to offer her a help when she really needs it.  For you it's a sweet revenge. But I have no reference to offer; not sure if it is a dialectical usage.

Answer (score 2):

*Reciprocation* is the word you're looking for. In simple words, *reciprocation* is the act of *[reciprocating](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reciprocate)*.

> **Reciprocation:** the fact of feeling or behaving towards someone else in the same way as they feel or behave towards you. [[CED]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/reciprocation)

*Reciprocation* often has positive connotations. *Retaliation* is often used in the same contexts with negative connotations.

You could also say *return the favour*.

For example, if someone does you a favour, you can reciprocate by doing the same thing (good for good) or you return the favour.

Answer (score 0):

"requital" is a noun not often used but exact in this context.

- I made them (a) requital.

It is used here for instance: [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=77gAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA113&dq=%22requital%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxtZ6WrZvrAhVG1xoKHa49C604ZBDoATAMegQIIBAC#v=onepage&q=%22requital%22&f=false).

[image]

*Addition*

Here are a few examples showing how the word is combined with the verb "make" or a similar one (from [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/requital) among a great many instances of use to be found there).

- For all the wrong of slavery requital must be **made**, submissively, ungrudgingly, repentantly.
- This was worth a requital, and they **got** it.
- A splendid monument was raised to his memory, on which was inscribed his own epitaph, that no friend ever did him a kindness, and no enemy a wrong, without **receiving** a full requital.
- Ever since the visit paid to her home by the imperial consort, he fulfilled his official duties with additional zeal, for the purpose of reverently **making** requital for the grace shown him by the Emperor.

Comment: If that is the best example you can find of this use, then *requital* is really not used in this sense.

Comment: @PeterShor SOED **1** Return or recompense for a service, effort, etc.  It is a countable noun (https://books.google.fr/books?id=-z5TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA276&dq=%22requital%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQtJC-ypvrAhXNxIUKHW0CB7g4yAEQ6AEwEXoECDoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22requital%22&f=false); as it is closely synonymous to "retribution" and that "to make a retribution" is idiomatic, how could "make a requital" not be correct? Moreover, in "Caesar ought to make you this requital." how can it be a quesstion of "requital" as "retaliation"? It is a matter of reward.

Comment: This is a *Latin exercise book*. It may not reflect actual natural usage of the English language.

Comment: @PeterShor It would be an error then; especially because there are several instances of that use, it is not likely to be an error. I'll keep looking for more examples though.

Comment: English speakers are much more likely to say *made in requital* rather than *made a requital* (*made a requital* actually sounds strange to me, although grammatically it's probably okay). [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made+in+requital%2C+made+a+requital&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmade%20in%20requital%3B%2Cc0). There is undoubtedly some Latin word whose best translation is *requital*.

Comment: @PeterShor I noticed that, it is true; nevertheless I found some examples showing that  various werbs can be used (for instance "perform") and I'll add that in my answer. Feel free to comment on this addition also, whatever ther idea or impression you might have.

Comment: My comment is that without an adjective, *requital* is usually treated as uncountable, so you don't need the "a".

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about usage, we are also talking about what people might  actually say.  Irony is a popular characteristic in British English.  So someone might say to a friend who just paid for a meal they shared:

> I’ll retaliate next time

or

> Next time we eat, I’ll have my own back

Comment: Some have said that it is easier to give than to receive!